# Custom Options should display in popup after click on Buy now button on product's view page magento

Tags: magento, popup

I have added some custom options in a product in magento admin panel, in frontend these custom option should display in popup after click the buy now button. same as 
http://www.lenskart.com/vincent-chase-vc2318-black-1010-eyeglasses.html

Please give any ideas how to do it

Custom Options should display in popup after click on Buy now button on product's view page

Comment: The example link you have provided doesnot popup custom option, i think you are getting it wrong.It is not the custom option

Comment: Can you please explain in details what it is ? and how it is working ?